# Entity Framework Code First Objecxt reference not set but present in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm struggling with a problem that never occurred to me until now..
I tried to implement an application with EF Code First with SQL CE Database.
I have these two main class that give me the specific problem:

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Unique { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }

    public virtual List<VideoExerciseResult> VideoSessionResults { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class VideoExerciseResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Unique { get; set; }        
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswerCorrect { get; set; }

    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

When I finish a session and save the results EF i sable to complete the operation and save both the session and the results on the db. 
I can check the fields looking directly in the .sdf files and the references to the Session_Id in the VideoExerciseResults column are present.

But when in the code I try to make this operation:

```
private void GetSessionData()
    {
        List<VideoExerciseResult> tempList2 = new List<VideoExerciseResult>(UOW.VideoSessionsResults.GetAll());
        ListOfVideoSessionResults = new ObservableCollection<VideoExerciseResult>((tempList2.Where(ver => ver.Session.Id == SelectedSession.Id)).ToList());
    }
```

It gives me error with the message:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

And in fact if I mouse hover on tempList2 some of the videoexerciseresult objects have the Session set to null, even thought there is a value in the .sdf file..

Did i miss something?

---

I will add the code regarding Session... 
It's based on a Repository and Unit Of Work schema I followed

```
public class EnPleinProjectUOW : IEnPleinProjectUOW, IDisposable
{
    private EnPleinProjectDbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    public IVideoExerciseResultRepository VideoSessionsResults
    {
        get { return GetRepo<IVideoExerciseResultRepository>(); }
    }

    public IPatientRepository Patients
    {
        get { return GetRepo<IPatientRepository>(); }
    }

    public ISessionRepository Sessions
    {
        get { return GetRepo<ISessionRepository>(); }
    }

    public ITestRepository Tests
    {
        get { return GetRepo<ITestRepository>(); }
    }

    public IImageFileRepository ImageFiles
    {
        get { return GetRepo<IImageFileRepository>(); }
    }

    // We need inverse of control
    public EnPleinProjectUOW(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbcontext();

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    private void CreateDbcontext()
    {
        DbContext = new EnPleinProjectDbContext();

        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }
    private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (DbContext != null)
            {
                DbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

And this is for the general commands:

```
public class EnPleinProjectRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    #region Properties

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public EnPleinProjectRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Dbcontext missing");

        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();

    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
            dbEntityEntry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        dbEntityEntry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        if (entity == null) return;
        Delete(entity);
    }

    public void DeleteAll()
    {
        foreach (T entity in DbSet)
            Delete(entity);
    }
```

But I', quite confident that this works since in the Database the data are saved and all the references... I don't know why some of them are not read back...

Thank you for the answers

Comment: We don't know what the UOW.VideoSessionsResults.GetAll() does, if that should return objects with the Session property filled (like in the db), something might go wrong there. Could you post that method as well? The error message is probably due to the fact that a Session is not set like you say, so checking the Id property in your  lambda would indeed throw an exception if that is null. So we need to find out why the Session property doesn't get set all the time...

Comment: `ListOfVideoSessionResults` didn't you mean `List<VideoSessionResults>`?

Comment: @Soner would you paste the code in the  UOW.VideoSessionsResults.GetAll() methods ?

Comment: @Ada Bell'h Mon Trésor: Soner is the editor not person asking the question

Comment: Yes thank you @bump but I'm talking to him (to Soner)

Comment: @Ada Bell'h Mon Trésor: He has the code as well?

Comment: @Tico No that is the name of the ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that doing the expression in a single line works:

```
ListOfVideoSessionResults = new ObservableCollection<VideoExerciseResult>(UOW.VideoSessionsResults.GetAll().Where(vsr => vsr.Session.Id == SelectedSession.Id));
```